# syntax error in expression in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
files=[ls .]
for file in $files
    do 
    digits=$(echo $file | sed "s/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p")
    if [[ $digits -gt 1000 ]]
    then
        rm $file 
    fi 
done
```

Why am I getting:

```
11923: syntax error in expression (error token is "11923")
```

where 11923 is an example of one printed line when the $digits variable has value 11923?

**EDIT:**

I have found the error. The debuger says that the value of the $digits is duplicated (ex '1001 1001'). I am not sure why this is happening, though. The output of the debugger:

```
+ for file in *
++ echo image10961.jpg
++ sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
+ digits='10961
10961'
+ [[ 10961
10961 -gt 1000 ]]
test.sh: line 5: [[: 10961
10961: syntax error in expression (error token is "10961")
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Make sure that there is always a number in variable $digits.

Comment: What is  contained in `$files`? Is it a  list of files? In any case you should be using an array, or more easily globing

Comment: $files is indeed a list of files, and $digits are always numbers. I have checked that sed does return a number, as all the files have the same pattern.

Comment: @AleksandarJovanovic : Could you show how you're populating the `$files` variable? Add the code please..

Comment: The unquoted variables could cause weird errors. See httpe//shellcheck.net/ for detailed diagnostics (generally *before* asking for human assistance).

Comment: @sjsam Here, code added. File names contain no whitespaces.

Comment: @AleksandarJovanovic Hmm.  But still it is safe to follow the best practices

Comment: Add a `-x` after the shebang to pin-point where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `ls` to populate the files as noted in [[ this ]](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

The easiest way is to use globbing  ie

```
for file in ./*
do
 # do something with $file
done
```

You may use the extended regex with `sed`

```
digits=$(echo "$file" | sed -E "s/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/p")
```

and note that `$file` is double quoted.

Regarding the error

```
11923: syntax error in expression (error token is "11923")
```

It is because you have added a `p` flag after the `sed` substitution.
Change it to

```
digits=$(echo "$file" | sed -E "s/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/")
```

By default `sed` prints stuff by default unless you use `-n` option

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is here:

```
files=[ls .]
```

This should use `$(...)` to execute a command and capture its output.

```
files=$(ls .)
```

Though, really, it's best to [avoid parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Better to get rid of `$files` and use `*` to loop over all the files in the current directory.

```
for file in *
```

Comment: The error still persists. If I exclude the if clause, and just echo $digits somwehere, everything works fine. Meaning that digits are extracted well, though I am definitely not using the best practices (sorry for that).

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified like this:

```
for file in *; do
    [[ $file =~ ([0-9]+) ]] && (( 10#${BASH_REMATCH[0]} > 1000 )) && rm "$file" 
done
```

It doesn't invoke `sed` for each file so it's more efficient. You can use a more advanced regex if this isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this script should work in your case

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./f*
do
    digits=$(echo -n $file | sed -n -e "s/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p")
    if [ $digits -gt 1000 ]
    then
        rm $file
    fi
done
```

Parsing the returned result in `ls` is tricky as mentioned in another answer. Here is a few things I changed to make it work.

First, `echo -n`, which will not to print extra new line character. 
Then `sed -n`, quiet mode for sed which will not print non matching lines
Last, more importantly, `[` has different syntax than `[[` . If you want to use `-gt`, you need to use `[`.

Comment: There's no need to suppress the newline with `echo -n`. Same with `sed -n`: this is a single file name, so using `p` and `-n` is unnecessary. "If you want to use `-gt`, you need to use `[`." Not true. `[[` supports `-gt`.